# How to break up expressions involve bitwise shift operators? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bit-manipulation

The code below is generating an error and fails to run as the expression was too 'complex'.

```
for row in 0...NumRows {
        for column in 0...NumColumns {
            let topLeft = (column > 0) && (row < NumRows)
                && level.tileAt(column: column - 1, row: row) != nil
            let bottomLeft = (column > 0) && (row > 0)
                && level.tileAt(column: column - 1, row: row - 1) != nil
            let topRight = (column < NumColumns) && (row < NumRows)
                && level.tileAt(column: column, row: row) != nil
            let bottomRight = (column < NumColumns) && (row > 0)
                && level.tileAt(column: column, row: row - 1) != nil

            let value = Int(topLeft.hashValue) | Int(topRight.hashValue) << 1 | Int(bottomLeft.hashValue) << 2 | Int(bottomRight.hashValue) << 3

            if value != 0 && value != 6 && value != 9 {

                let name = String(format: "Tile_%ld", value)
                let tileNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: name)
                tileNode.size = CGSize(width: TileWidth, height: TileHeight)
                var point = pointFor(column: column, row: row)
                point.x -= TileWidth/2
                point.y -= TileHeight/2
                tileNode.position = point
                tilesLayer.addChild(tileNode)

            }
        }
    }
```

Specifically this line:

```
let value = Int(topLeft.hashValue) | Int(topRight.hashValue) << 1 | Int(bottomLeft.hashValue) << 2 | Int(bottomRight.hashValue) << 3
```

The error is as follows:

> Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

How would you break up the expression for value in such a way that the code following it keeps the same answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hashValue` is already an `Int`, so the `Int(...)` constructors are not
needed. This compiles in Xcode 9:

```
let value = topLeft.hashValue | (topRight.hashValue << 1) | (bottomLeft.hashValue << 2) | (bottomRight.hashValue << 3)
```

But that is a **bad idea!** It relies on the hash value of booleans having specific values:

```
false.hashValue == 0
true.hashValue == 1
```

which is nowhere guaranteed. (The *only*  guarantee is that identical elements have the same hash value. One must not even assume that hash
values are equal across different executions of your program,
see [`Hashable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable)).

A better solution would be

```
let value = (topLeft ? 1 : 0) + (topRight ? 2 : 0) + (bottomLeft ? 4 : 0) + (bottomRight ? 8 : 0)
```

Alternatively, use a switch-statement. Example:

```
switch (topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight) {
case (false, false, false, false):
    // ... all false ...
case (false, true, true, false):
    // ... topRight and bottomLeft are true ...
case (true, false, false, true):
    // ... topLeft and bottomRight are true ...
default:
    // ... all other cases ...
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, especially the part about not relying on boolean's hashValue